ReadTheDocs build doesn't produce an index file
While not building documentation that used to work just fine before recently a rebuild produced
Error

Your documentation did not generate an index.html at its root directory. This is required for documentation serving at the root URL for this version.

The YAML config file I used is fairly standard
# .readthedocs.yaml
# Read the Docs configuration file
# See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html for details

# Required
version: 2

# Set the version of Python and other tools you might need
build:
  os: ubuntu-22.04
  tools:
    python: "3.12"

# Build documentation in the docs/api directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
  builder: html
  configuration: docs/api/conf.py
  # TODO: needs dropping of additional customizations
  fail_on_warning: false

# Build docs in additional formats such as PDF and ePub
formats: all

# Specify dependencies to enable reproducible builds:
# https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/reproducible-builds.html
python:
  install:
    - requirements: packaging/pip_requirements_minimal.txt
    - method: pip
      path: ./packaging/

Does anyone happen to know that does RTD want from me?

Turns out RTD posted about it:
https://blog.readthedocs.com/builds-without-index/
which I link that would have done nicely as part of their error message to begin with, especially if it is a breaking behavior and some projects may rebuild documentation once per year.
This being said, I place an index.rst from the project's GH README (conversion from MarkDown using pandoc) and build the documentation fine locally, just have a warning about the index.rst remotely since they are doing something else unexpected.
I apologize if if StackOverflow is not the right place to post such technical details, it turns out their support is mostly for businesses and their "support forum" (or the one they point to) is simply StackOverflow.
